# Deprecated: Automatic TCA migration

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have the same problem after upgrading Typo3 CMS from version 8 to version 9, the upgrade wizard don't run and show this error:

> Ajax error
>
> Deprecated: Automatic TCA migration done during bootstrap. Please
> adapt TCA accordingly, these migrations will be removed. The backend
> module "Configuration -> TCA" shows the modified values. Please adapt
> these areas: The TCA table 'pages_language_overlay' is not used
> anymore and has been removed automatically in order to avoid negative
> side-effects. in
> /home/deindesi/public_html/typo3_src-9.5.31/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/ExtensionManagementUtility.php
> on line 1731
>
> {"success":true,"needsUpdate":true,"adds":{"columns":[{"table":"pages","field":"rowDescription"},{"table":"pages","field":"sys_language_uid"},{"table":"pages","field":"l10n_parent"},{"table":"pages","field":"l10n_source"},{"table":"pages","field":"l10n_state"},{"table":"pages","field":"l10n_diffsource"},{"table":"pages","field":"slug"},{"table":"pages","field":"legacy_overlay_uid"},{"table":"sys_history","field":"actiontype"},{"table":"sys_history","field":"usertype"},{"table":"sys_history","field":"userid"},{"table":"sys_history","field":"originaluserid"},{"table":"sys_history","field":"workspace"},{"table":"tt_content","field":"filelink_sorting_direction"},{"table":"tx_scheduler_task","field":"deleted"},{"table":"index_phash","field":"static_page_arguments"},{"table":"sys_note","field":"position"}],"indexes":[{"table":"pages","index":"language_identifier"},{"table":"pages","index":"slug"},{"table":"pages","index":"translation_source"},{"table":"sys_file","index":"parent"},{"table":"sys_file_metadata","index":"parent"},{"table":"sys_file_reference","index":"t3ver_oid"},{"table":"tt_content","index":"translation_source"},{"table":"tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_repository","index":"parent"},{"table":"tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_extension","index":"parent"}]}}

I have tried to clear the cache,
also i have set the display errors to 1.

I don't know how to change this TCA config so the upgrade can run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is still experiencing this problem after disabling all extensions:

After **removing** the following line in the 'SYS' section of the LocalConfiguration.php, I was able to access the upgrade wizard again.

```
'errorHandler' => '',
```

Answer (score 1):

The table `pages_language_overlay` has been [removed in TYPO3 v9](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.0/Important-82445-MigratePagesLanguageOverlayIntoPages.html). Most probably you have an extension installed which is incompatible.

You should disable all extensions and the run the upgrade wizards. Afterwards you can update and activate all extensions one after the other.

Comment: I have disabled all the extensions but the problem is still there.
This project is from v6, i have upgrade it to version 7 with no problem,
then i have upgrade it to v8, i run the upgrade wizard , there is some database ALTER TABLE that didn't finish to exexute (i don't know why, they are stuck there). So i have installed the v9 core and i find this problem.